# Deep copy of vector<Point> myArr

Tags: c++, vector, member, deep-copy, libstdc++

In order to make a deep copy of `myArr`,

```
vector <Point> myArr;
```

where `Point` is a class with 2 ints as members,

Do I need to do something special? or is ok with

```
vector <Point> otherArr = myArr;
```

I need to delete some points in `otherArr` but at the same time I need all the points in `myArr` for later usage.

thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't have one, consider getting [a good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list).  It is critical to have a good understanding of the memory model and object model when programming in C++.

Comment: I recognize that memory management is the thing I have to work the most in C++, but is just every time I start reading a book they talk about HOW to program and the GRAMMAR rules and that I already know  from other programming languages...  If you could suggest a specific book for memory management It would be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Shallow vs Deep Copies](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-condestructors/shallowdeepcopy.html) and [Effective C++](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-cpp/oop-condestructors/shallowdeepcopy.html)

**`Point` does not need deep copy.** As a thumb rule, "deep copy" is required when a class has pointer members. The `Point` class have only two `int` members, so it does not require any special effort for "deep copy", the normal or "shallow copy" would do perfectly fine. In fact, it is not *required* to write a copy-constructor for `Point`, the default or synthesized one provided by the compiler would do just fine.

Regarding your second question, after the line

```
vector< Point > otherArr = myArr;
```

is executed, `otherArr` and `myArr` are two **independent** vectors. Operations (e.g. delete some elements) performed on one of them does not affect the other in any way.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer and for the links ;) I found they very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment should be fine. It makes sure that all data is copied over right. Just make sure that Point is copyable.

Comment: How do I make Point copyable? what would happen if is not? thanks ;)

Comment: If `Point` is noncopyable, you can't have a `vector<Point>` (in C++03, at least).

Answer (score 1):

What you have is fine. The vector has an overloaded assignment operator and copy constructor that perform a deep copy.

Comment: The assignment operator will not be invoked; this is an initialization, not an assignment.